# CRC check program

Tags: reverse-engineering, analysis, speech, crc, data-integrity

I have a speech file on a alarm device i'd like to change/rerecord. the files are in VOX format ADPCM (NLEN1.bin) and i can play them in audacity. and re record them in cool edit. successfully created the same 512kb file size 
the problem is putting them back to the alarm device. i need to supply a bsc file with CRC values from the speech files. how do i get the CRC values for my new recorded speech files?

if i do a CRC check on the original files i cant get the values given in the bsc file.
since i am reverse engineering, i assume i need CRC16

BSC file:

4278904898  NLEN1.bin

4280806306  NLEN2.bin

4280731940  NLEN3.bin

4291163785  NLEN4.bin

Comment: The unsigned integer values in the file would require 32 bits.  Perhaps a CRC-32?

Comment: the BCN file says NLEN2.bin HAS a CRC of 4280806306, if i do a CRC32 check on the file i get 9e4caa3c, hex-> DEC = 2655824444

Comment: There are many possible CRC-32 polynomial, initial register contents, and bit/word inversion/reversal possibilities.  What does 'BCN'/'BSC' mean?  Why do you think the integers should be CRC's?

Comment: the extention is bsc. (made a typo with BCN) the first time we uploaded the new recorded file it gave a CRC error. then we changed one of the numbers in bcs file with the original speech files. and it came up with a "CRC error" before loading.

Comment: Good experiment.  No docs or source code for this CRC generation?  How about trying all the popular CRC-32 algorithms?

Comment: so far i tried CRC32, MD5 and SHA-1. so yeah its a bit of a puzzle. i was kinda hoping i did it wrong. and have no experience in the CRC department. so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There are many possibilities.  Really need to try a lot of 32-bit CRC/checksum possibilities.  Too bad there's no documentation nor code to look at for your particular system.

Comment: i uploaded the files and the original file to https://app.box.com/s/t2wejrxi1iamw8ygpv7p

Comment: Would you upload the other bin files in case some differential analysis is fruitful?

Comment: I just added the other 3 files. the NLEN1.bin is my modified file. the other 3 files are the original ones.

Comment: Let me know if the answer below is sufficient or requires more explanation/development.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. its been quite busy at work. but still like to get it going. i installed Python for windows to run your script. but no time to explore more. hope thats the good way to run the script.

Comment: The code below just demos the technique, if you need a runnable Python script, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of "observing" with [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) and [Udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) and also a bit of Python hacking, I was able to determine the checksum scheme used with the `.bin` and `.bsc` files.

Here's a little Python code (from within 'ipython') that shows how to generate the required checksum:

```
In [1]: f=open('NLEN2.bin','r')

In [2]: s=f.read()

In [3]: from arraymodule import *

In [4]: my_int8s=[b for b in array('b',s)]

In [5]: my_int8s[:10]
Out[5]: [2, -103, -110, 0, -128, -128, 0, 10, -125, 10]

In [6]: my_checksum=sum(my_int8s)%(2**32)

In [7]: my_checksum
Out[7]: 4280806306L
```

N.B.:  The program appeared to sum exactly 524288 bytes in each `.bin` file.

N.B.:  The Python above could be made faster/smaller if desired.

***EDIT***

Here's the "script" without the ipython line numbers, etc., and hopefully works on your Windows platform.

```
f=open('NLEN2.bin','rb')
s=f.read()
from array import *
my_int8s=[b for b in array('b',s)]
my_checksum=sum(my_int8s)%(2**32)
print("Checksum: %d\n" % my_checksum)
```

Comment: @Roelofzo :  If this answer is correct, please accept it by clicking the check mark and consider an upvote.  Also, please consider editing your question to name the system you are working on so that your question will more likely help others too.  Regards.

Comment: python for windows doesnt seem to come with arraymodule     ImportError: No module named arraymodule

Comment: Which version of python is it?  I believe I was using version 2.7.5 or maybe 2.7.6.

Comment: 2.6.7 in windows. Ohw its just a result screen? lol. thats probably why it won't run LOL. if you dont mind posting the pyhton script, id like to edit the sound files and see if i can create a valid CRC. then see if the alarm box will play our new recorded sound files.

Comment: I edited the answer showing python without ipython line numbers, etc.  If you don't have a lot of files, this may be sufficient.  If you have to do this a lot with different files, a python script that accepts a commandline argument would be more convenient.

Comment: well i only have 4 files per language set. so this is fine. i'm still having trouble finding the "arraymodule" its looking for.

Comment: Try just "array" instead of "arraymodule".

Comment: yeah that worked!!! however i'm getting different numbers then you. here i my results. what it sould be VS what i am getting.. am i doing something wrong? I'm using the un touched files so that should give me the original number.

4280806306 NLEN2.bin-> 4294964227
4280731940 NLEN3.bin-> 4294966668
4291163785 NLEN4.bin

Comment: Edited answer for another try.  I only use Windows once a year to file tax returns so I'm not as fluent with it (and there is a lot of associated pain).  8-)

Comment: YES YES YES it works!!!! i wont be able to upload it yet . but this looks really promising!! THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!!

Comment: ok Ive uploaded the file and it does accept the file. but after the upload it says error, because all files are 512KB and my modified file is 513KB. I need more information on ADPCM files. and the software that is used on creating the speech files. right now there are about 20 sentences in one file. how does the machine know where one line starts and ends? and how can i modify a sound file and create exactly 512kb?

Comment: Lots of new questions.  What happens if you truncate your new file to the accepted length?